# Update query using object

Tags: mysql, node.js, node-mysql

I'm using npm package mysql and I want to do an update query that gets an object and knows what are the fields that need an update

```
function editPlaylistDB(publicID, name, description,callback) {

    let insertData={};
    if (name!==null){
        insertData.name=name;
    }
    if(description!==null){
        insertData.description=description;
    }

     db.query('update playlists set name=insertData.name,description=description  WHERE public_id= ?',[publicID]).then((rows=>{
        console.log(rows);
        callback(rows);

    })).catch((err)=>{
        console.log(err);
        callback(null);
    });
}
```

This is the error message

```
Error: ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR: Unknown column 'insertData.name' in 'field list'
```

I don't know if it is even possible.

Answer (score 1):

Why not add another parameterized variable like the public_id? Also, it looks like your description was not being set correctly either. Also, double check how you are setting insertData.description and where that should go.

```
db.query('update playlists set name=?,description=?  WHERE public_id= ?',[insertData.name, (description var goes here), publicID]).then((rows=>{
    console.log(rows);
    callback(rows);

})).catch((err)=>{
    console.log(err);
    callback(null);
});
```

Comment: Updated, looks like your description column was not being set correctly either.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you need to use parameterised string:

```
`update playlists set name=${insertData.name},description=${description}  WHERE public_id= ?`
```